# Explicit formula for a power series asymptotic approximation of $z^u$ given any complex exponent $u$.

Tags: special-functions, exponentiation, closed-form, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Given any fixed $u\in\mathbb{C}$, does there exist a general form of the $n$-th term of a power series of $z^u$ ?

For such $u$ we would have a Laurent Series expansion like
$$c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint z^u\frac{dz}{z^{1+n}}$$
and
$$z^u=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} c_nz^n$$
convergent in some open annulus/disk/subset of the complex plane.

Is there any simplified general formula for $c_n=c_n(u)$ in terms of elementary/special functions, even in fractional powers such as Puiseux series?

Comment: How do you define $z^u$?

Comment: Its defined as $e^{u\log(z)}$.

Comment: And what does $\log(z)$ mean?

Comment: The complex logarithm of $z$, it can be defined multivaluated. $\ln(|z|)+i\arg(z)$.

Composing the Laurent series of one branch of it with the Taylor series the complex exponential function yields an ugly expression of $c_n$ in terms of products of sums, and I wonder if there is some known simplification of such infinite nested sum.

Comment: Since it is multivalued, it is not a function. Therefore, neither is $z^u$ and it makes no sense to talk about a Laurent series of a thing which is not a function.

Comment: And therefore What does its usual expansions are? For example http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/log.htm

Comment: @DrPotato These power series are for real variables only (and within a certain range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read already in the comments, $z\mapsto z^u$ is in general not a proper function since the $\log$ in the definition is not jet a unique value. Note that for $u\in\mathbb{Z}_{<0}$ this multivalued $\log$ is just deleted again by the $\exp$ function's periodicity. So these $u$, which may have made you writing this question, are a very special case to still yield holomorphic functions around $0$, whose Laurent series then consequently (makes sense and) converge.

Comment: Indeed by definition $z^u=e^{u\log(z)}$, where $\log(z)$ is multivalued, but could we find not a Laurent series but some sort of expansion as [Expansion around a singular point of a multivalued meromorphic function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386960/expansion-around-a-singular-point-of-a-multivalued-meromorphic-function-due-to) reads?

Comment: There could be also an answer in terms of [Asymptotic expansion about branch point](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1958024/622884) for example.

Comment: You mean as a Puiseux series?

Comment: I don't think you can resolve the problem of generally multiple values if your mapping is a fractional power law. You can always at most define such a map as holomorphic on the plane without a ray starting in (and containing) the pole/singularity. Then the whole idea of integrating around the pole breaks down as you must leave the holomorphicity domain. Btw: the Wiki on Puiseux series says that to view such a series as a mapping of complex numbers you must coose a branch of the respective $n$-th root.